# Powerpoint - make add-in compatible with more versions of PowerPoint

Tags: ms-office, add-in, powerpoint

I'm programming simple powerpoint add-in, that sends xmlhttp request on slide change. Is it possible to create one add-in compatible with more vesions of powerpoint? Or do I have to develop it for each version separately? How to develop add-ins for more versions of MS Office without installing all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what tools you're using to develop the add-in. My understanding is that if you want to write for multiple versions of PPT using Visual Studio, you're more or less out of luck, unless you have multiple computers or multiple VMs and whatnot.

If you're using VBA, then it's not especially difficult to write one add-in that's compatible with all versions as far back as 2000. There are a few tricks to it, and it becomes a lot simpler if you leave PowerPoint 97 out of the mix.

Comment: Thank you I'm gonna look closer on VBA.

Comment: Good plan, I think.  Certainly, it's easier to get started automating PPT using VBA, and anything you learn about the PowerPoint object model will be useful if you decide that .NET is better for your needs.  If you need help making add-ins and getting started in VBA, I've got a PowerPoint FAQ site at pptfaq.com that might prove useful.  These are notes from a seminar I taught a while back; they're a bit out of date but might also be useful:  http://www.steverindsberg.com/pptlive/